# How to differentiate between the cases and translate

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below lines in my XML document.

```
<orderedlist type="manual">
<item num="1."><para>identify the issues in dispute;</para></item>
<item num="1.1"><para>explore and generate options;</para></item>
<item num="1.1.1"><para>communicate with one another; and/or</para></item>
<orderedlist>
```

i need to differentiate the three `item`.

If it is `1.`(i mean if there is only one `.`) i want to print it as it is, and for the rest 2, i want to translate `.` to `-`.

please let me know how can i do this. also please let me know, how can i check if there is any number after `.`.

Thanks

Comment: Would ends-with `'.'` be a good criterion?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, sorry i didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: Assuming you are using XSLT 2.0 as indicated, `ends-with(@num, '.')` will return true for the first item in your example, false for the other two.

Comment: and how do i seperate, case 2 and 3?

Comment: You don't, you treat them the same - isn't that what you said?

Comment: Yes you are right @michael.hor257k, i want to know a regex that does this.

Comment: If I am right, then why doesn't this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="item">
<xsl:variable name="afterFirstPeriod" select="substring-after(@num,'.')"/>
<xsl:variable name="afterSecondPeriod" select="substring-after(substring-after(@num,'.'),'.')"/>
<xsl:variable name="beforeFirstPeriod" select="substring-before(@num,'.')"/>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$afterSecondPeriod">
<xsl:value-of select="$beforeFirstPeriod"/>-<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($afterFirstPeriod,'.')"/>*<xsl:value-of select="$afterSecondPeriod"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$afterFirstPeriod">
<xsl:value-of select="$beforeFirstPeriod"/>-<xsl:value-of select="$afterFirstPeriod"/>
</xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```